# How to install drivers in ubuntu 14.04 final beta

Tags: drivers

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 final beta. But i am looking for a way to install drivers for Nvidia graphic card, wireless card, touchpad.

My laptop has a NVIDIA GEFORCE 710M with 2GB Dedicated VRAM graphics card

Also i am not able to change the brightness of screen with fn+(required key). How should i fix it? Should i install intel graphics drivers as well?

I much worried about graphics drivers because i want to play games via stream :)

Laptop: Acer Aspire E1-571G

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What about this? The steps should be similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers

Comment: @jmunsch even touchpad glitches too much...sometime it doesn't respond how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abhimanyu,

Try searching for "Additional Drivers" from the Unity Dash (like the Windows start menu).  I'm using an NVIDIA graphics card; here is what mine looks like:

[image: My Additional Drivers View]

You can adjust your brightness from the System Settings menu, again search-able from the Unity Dash.  You can also get there by clicking on the gear in the top-right corner of your screen.  Brightness and Lock is the second one.

If I may get on a soap box for a few words...you should always update your system before making any changes like this.  It is quick and easy [from Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: its showing me >>>>using nvidia binary driver: version 331.38 from nvidia 331(proprietary, tested) should i choose it??

Comment: It sounds like it could be the driver you want.  However, I would definitely update first and be sure to backup anything you don't want to lose.  Beta versions are not meant to be depended-on for seamless operation, they are meant to be improved upon.

Comment: Done working now how can i see graphic help and tweak center

Comment: That's good news.  In Windows, you would modify the NVIDIA settings from the NVIDIA console.  In Ubuntu, most options are available from the same System Settings described in my answer.  Please remember to mark the answer to your question.